# Binding additionall parameters to event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

**Use case:**

I've got an event handler which already gets passed one parameter (an error object). At the place where I am binding the event handler I'd like to pass an additional parameter. I know there is the `bind()` method, but I think I would overwrite the existing error parameter.

**Code:**

```
const client = new RequestClient(...);

// Here I want to bind the client object so that onClientError gets the
// error and the client object passed
client.onError(this.onClientError); 

private onClientError = (error: Error): void => {
  this.logger.error(`Error on client occured: ${error}`);
};

// And this is how I'd like to use my new event handler
private onClientError = (error: Error, client: RequestClient): void => {
  this.logger.error(`Error on client occured: ${error}`);
};
```

**My question:**

How can I bind additional parameters to an event handler if it already has an existing parameter?

Comment: Does it have to be the second parameter? It's easy if it can be the first one instead.

Comment: Why not combine the two parameters inside a common function and call that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` is indeed what you want **if** you're okay with the extra parameter being the *first* parameter instead of the second:

```
client.onError(this.onClientError.bind(null, client)); 

private onClientError = (client: RequestClient, error: Error): void => {
  this.logger.error(`Error on client occured: ${error}`);
};
```

When the function `bind` returns is called, it calls the original function with any arguments you give it when calling `bind` followed by the ones it was called with. So if you `bind` argument A and it gets called with argument B, the original function is called with arguments A and B (in that order).

If it has to be second, the simplest thing is a wrapper function:

```
client.onError(event => this.onClientError(event, client));
```

Comment: Oh alright, I don't mind if it's the first or second parameter I just thought it overwrites the parameter. Great!

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation on that point to the answer, since I just kind of implied what happens rather than actually saying it. :-)